# taking a double digit integer in an array and storing as two single digit integers

Tags: c

The simplest way I can explain what I am trying to accomplish if the user inputs `6` it gets stored in the `numbers[0]` index which is then multiplied by `2` which gives it a product of `12` but instead of storing `12` in the `0` index of the `productValue` array it needs to store it as `productValue[0] = 1` `productValue[1] = 2` I am having trouble getting it to store the individual integers. I am new to C so give me a break if this seems overly simple to accomplish. My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char numbers[17];
    char productValue[8];
    int i, x;
    printf("Please enter number\n");
    scanf("%s", numbers);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i += 2)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            productValue[x] = (numbers[i] - '0') * 2; 
            printf("%d\n", productValue[x]);
            i += 2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to add the carry, no need for 2 loops

Comment: "simplest way I can explain " -- there's an easier way, using the concept of a *representation*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sprintf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char productValue[8];
  int i, x, number,result;
  printf("Please enter number\n");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  result = number * 2;
  sprintf(productValue, "%d", result);
  printf("%s\n", productValue);
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store integers, you could simply do a loop like this, where you check for each digit before moving on to the next one. Essentially, getting the number mod 10 will give you the digit for that place. The first line will line up the array to start with the last digit first, and continue from there. There is some error checking and whatnot that is important as well, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the user.

```
int index=floor(log10(number));
while (number>0)
{
   productValue[index--]=number%10;
   number/=10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the carry. There is also no need for 2 loops. `int i, x;` This line is useless in your code since you redefine them within the loop

```
char numbers[17];
char productValue[18];
int carry= 0;
...
for(int i=1;i<17;i++)
{
    productValue[i] = carry+(numbers[i] - '0') * 2; 
    carry = productValue[i]>=10?1:0;
    productValue[i] = productValue[i] %10;
}
productValue[17] = carry;
```